# how can release memory from view controller in swift

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

I need to know how can i (release/free) memory from view controller in tab bar controller project, the deinit method not call for the both view controller. I use the instrument tool it's show me it is in the memory and not free it

the following is my code for the both view controllers
the first view controller in tapped application is :

```
import UIKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    deinit {
        print("web view controller is De init")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

}
```

and the second view controller in the same project in tapped application is the following :

```
import UIKit

class MovieDownloadingViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    deinit {
        print("Movie Downloading View Controller is De init")
    }



}
```

you can try the code and see the deinit method not call

please when is the strong reference , wrong code which  leak  memory so it can't release memory from theses view controllers ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

i solve it 
am get the reference for the view controller from the viewWillDisappear()

```
 let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Web") as? WebViewController
        if vc != nil {
          vc = nil
        }
```

and set it to nil so the deinit is call

Comment: No, all this does is create yet another instance of the view controller and you're seeing its `deinit` getting called. But the original view controller instance is still banging about in memory.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to release view controllers as you select tabs, you shouldn't use a tab bar controller, but rather you should roll your own (use tab view, and do view controller containment calls to add and remove child view controllers as you select tabs).

But the deeper question is why would you want to go through all of that? The amount of memory used by view controllers is negligible. If you're trying to solve memory issues, identify what's taking up the significant amount of memory, and release only that, not the view controller, in `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: @RB1509 - I’m talking about RAM (e.g. iPhone 12 has 4gb, the iPhone 12 Pro has 6gb, etc.), the memory that is used when the app is running. E.g. see [Reducing Your App’s Memory Use](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/improving_your_app_s_performance/reducing_your_app_s_memory_use).

Comment: okay thank i will delete all above comments.

Answer (score 1):

Because the view controllers are presented by a tab bar view controller, the tab bar view controller will hold a reference to them until it is deallocated.

You can try to replace the tab bar view controller with something else to see your view controllers will be freed then.

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
```

After the above line is executed, both your `deinit` should be called.

Comment: Thank you very much where put this code? In view will disappear?

Comment: it's de init the both i need when i leave the view controller is de init only

Comment: if i set the view controller to the tab bar ,it's deleted so how can i still using the tab bar with view controller without strong reference with view controllers please?